# Inrush Current DC-DC boost converter

Tags: inrush-current

Worried about the effects of inrush current. I'm currently making a boost converter with an off the shelf DC-DC boost controller. The circuit also uses a quad op-amp(say,LM324N) for some supplementary operations that is powered directly from the input voltage. The input and the output capacitors used have a total capacitance of about 1000uf. 
             My question is, can the inrush current at the time of start-up effect such parallel loads in the circuit? Do I have to provide soft start for the op-amp chip  (the controller has its integrated soft start feature)?
              Inrush current effect series elements not the parallel components like ICs that have relatively lower supply currents , is that statement true?

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear what you are asking, but the inrush current of the boost converter itself has nothing to do with the load the boost converter is powering.  Whatever is powering the boost converter will see the inrush, and will have to deal with it, but the load that the boost converter is powering will just see a small delay in its power voltage coming up.

Since the boost converter itself has a soft start feature, its output will not be subjected to excessively large inrush due to capacitance of the load.  Even so, that wouldn't matter to the load either.

Inrush pretty much matters to everything *except* the load that is connected to the supply feed that is causing the inrush.

Comment: Thanx. Lets keep inrsuh currents aside for a moment. Suppose we have a VS that has a 1000uf cap in parallel and circuit has few sophisticated ICs. For few micro sec. the circuit allows huge currents to flow through the capacitor (ignore ESR). Will this affect other parallel IC's in the circuit. In other words if I short the VS output directly, a lot of stress will be on the wire but how would the other such components behave which are in parallel? Will they not be damaged? Its more of a practical question. I know current will always flow from least resistance and that will burn the traces.

Comment: What does 'VS' stand for?

Comment: @Bruce: I don't know.  I just checked and I didn't use that term anywhere, so its not clear what you are asking about.